# NextJS get custom JSON depending on page

Tags: json, next.js

I know you can do the following

```
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {

    console.log(params)
    const res = await fetch(`https://example.com/api-access/news/2021_autumn_home_style_tips`)
    const data = await res.json()
  
    if (!data) {
      return {
        notFound: true,
      }
    }
  
    return {
      props: { data }, // will be passed to the page component as props
    }
  }
```

however what if the last part depending on the news item a user presses needs to change.

```
https://example.com/api-access/news/2021_autumn_home_style_tips
https://example.com/api-access/news/2020_autumn_home_style_tips
https://example.com/api-access/news/2021_car
https://example.com/api-access/news/top_songs
```

How can I make a [slug].js page that allows me to run that slug url for example

https://myexample.com/news/top_songs
would fetch data from `https://example.com/api-access/news/top_songs`

I have tried

```
export const getStaticPaths: GetStaticPaths<{ slug: string }> = async () => {


    console.log(params)
    const res = await fetch('https://example.com/api-access/news/{slug}')
    const data = await res.json()
  
    if (!data) {
      return {
        notFound: true,
      }
    }
  
    return {
      props: { data }, // will be passed to the page component as props
    }
  }
```

But get this error[image: error]

Comment: Did you read the nextjs docs for getStaticPaths? https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticpaths-static-generation - I believe you'd need a combination of getStaticProps and getStaticPaths on your dynamic routes page

Comment: Also, in regards to the error itself, are you actually using TypeScript in your project (doesn't look like it by the file extension `[slug].js`)? If not, then simply remove `: GetStaticPaths<{ slug: string }>` from your `getStaticPaths` function declaration.